# Adding Russian yazerty keyboard prevents super + p and super + r to be effective

Tags: awesome-wm

I have been running Awesome for quite a time with fcitx enabled for being able to use Japanese and French input. Everything was fine.
I have added Russian yazerty keyboard and then  super + p and super + r are no longer effective while super + space or the other super shorcuts I use are fine.
What can I do to fix this annoying issue?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to add Russian yazerty keyboard to fcitx but instead to as described https://simpleit.rocks/linux/switch-keyboard-layouts

So I have a script  ~/bin/ruskey  which reads as follow :

```
#!/bin/bash
setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout fr,ru -variant oss,phonetic_yazherty -option grp:ctrls_toggle
```